# Instant BTC to USD transfer?

Tags: transactions, wallet, money-transfer

is there a way to have BTC sent from somewhere to my wallet and then that amount is immediately transferred to USD? I know that Coinbase offered this once but they have since removed that feature. I am just wondering if there is a similar service out there.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a product recommendation question, which isn't in the scope of this site. You can search the many bitcoin exchanges there are several that allow transferring between fiat and bitcoin. Note this depends on the country you live in as well.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check [BTCPay Server](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/81h1oy/the_merchants_guide_to_accepting_bitcoin_directly/)

More links for [source](https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver) and [documentation](https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver-doc).

In the past I would have recommended BitPay, but they've had too many red-flags that show that this company does not have the best interest of Bitcoin in mind.